# Can somebody explain this obfuscated perl regexp script?

Tags: perl

This code is taken from the [HackBack DIY guide to rob banks](https://unicornriot.ninja/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/hackback-announce-text.txt) by Phineas Fisher. It outputs a long text ([The Sixth Declaration of the Lacandon Jungle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sixth_Declaration_of_the_Lacandon_Jungle)). Where does it fetch it? I don't see any alphanumeric characters at all. What is going on here? And what does the -r switch do? It seems undocumented.

```
perl -Mre=eval <<\EOF
                                   ''                                     
                                  =~(                                     
                                  '(?'                                    
                                 .'{'.(                                   
                                '`'|'%'                                   
                                ).("\["^                                  
                               '-').('`'|                                 
                              '!').("\`"|                                 
                              ',').'"(\\$'                                
                             .':=`'.(('`')|                               
                            '#').('['^'.').                               
                            ('['^')').("\`"|                              
 ',').('{'^'[').'-'.('['^'(').('{'^'[').('`'|'(').('['^'/').('['^'/').(   
'['^'+').('['^'(').'://'.('`'|'%').('`'|'.').('`'|',').('`'|'!').("\`"|   
  '#').('`'|'%').('['^'!').('`'|'!').('['^'+').('`'|'!').('['^"\/").(     
     '`'|')').('['^'(').('['^'/').('`'|'!').'.'.('`'|'%').('['^'!')       
        .('`'|',').('`'|'.').'.'.('`'|'/').('['^')').('`'|"\'").          
          '.'.('`'|'-').('['^'#').'/'.('['^'(').('`'|('$')).(             
             '['^'(').('`'|',').'-'.('`'|'%').('['^('(')).                
                '/`)=~'.('['^'(').'|</'.('['^'+').'>|\\'                  
                   .'\\'.('`'|'.').'|'.('`'|"'").';'.                     
                     '\\$:=~'.('['^'(').'/<.*?>//'                        
                     .('`'|"'").';'.('['^'+').('['^                       
                    ')').('`'|')').('`'|'.').(('[')^                      
                   '/').('{'^'[').'\\$:=~/('.(('{')^                      
                   '(').('`'^'%').('{'^'#').('{'^'/')                     
                  .('`'^'!').'.*?'.('`'^'-').('`'|'%')                    
                 .('['^'#').("\`"|    ')').('`'|'#').(                    
                 '`'|'!').('`'|          '.').('`'|'/')                   
                .'..)/'.('['               ^'(').'"})')                   
                ;$:="\."^                     '~';$~='@'                  
               |'(';$^=                          ')'^'[';                 
              $/='`'                                |'.';                 
              $,=                                      '('           
EOF
```

Comment: Thanks, that explains a lot, but not enough for me to decipher the regexp.

Comment: To further what @toolic said, it's actually the `-M` (ie. use Module) directive, which means `use re;`. The `=eval` puts the `re` module into its `eval` mode. If in a script, it would look something like `use re qw(eval);`. Regarding the regex, obfu like this is designed to be looked at, not worked out ;)

Comment: Relevant Perlmonk post: [The History of Acme::Bleach and Acme::EyeDrops](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=967004), and FYI, the module [Acme::EyeDrops](https://metacpan.org/pod/Acme::EyeDrops) generates the same kind of codes you are looking at.

Comment: Thanks, very funny and cool! This starts making sense. How can I convert it back? I haven't found anything on the EyeDrops page. Is there a debugger feature that can show me the "real* code? Sorry, I rarely use perl.

Comment: `perltidy` is a useful perl pretty-printer and formatter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The basic idea of the code you posted is that each alphanumeric character has been replaced by a bitwise operation between two non-alphanumeric characters. For instance,

```
'`'|'%'
```

(5th line of the "star" in your code)
Is a bitwise or between backquote and modulo, whose codepoints are respectively 96 and 37, whose "or" is 101, which is the codepoint of the letter "e". The following few lines all print the same thing:

```
say '`' | '%' ;
say chr( ord('`' | '%') );
say chr( ord('`') | ord('%') );
say chr( 96 | 37 );
say chr( 101 );
say "e"
```

Your code starts with (ignore whitespaces which don't matter):

```
'' =~ (
```

The corresponding closing bracket is 28 lines later:

```
^'(').'"})')
```

(C-f this pattern to see it on the web-page; I used my editor's matching parenthesis highlighting to find it)

We can assign everything in between the opening and closing parenthesis to a variable that we can then print:

```
$x =                              '(?'
                                 .'{'.(
                                '`'|'%'
                                ).("\["^
                               '-').('`'|
                              '!').("\`"|
                              ',').'"(\\$'
                             .':=`'.(('`')|
                            '#').('['^'.').
                            ('['^')').("\`"|
 ',').('{'^'[').'-'.('['^'(').('{'^'[').('`'|'(').('['^'/').('['^'/').(
'['^'+').('['^'(').'://'.('`'|'%').('`'|'.').('`'|',').('`'|'!').("\`"|
  '#').('`'|'%').('['^'!').('`'|'!').('['^'+').('`'|'!').('['^"\/").(
     '`'|')').('['^'(').('['^'/').('`'|'!').'.'.('`'|'%').('['^'!')
        .('`'|',').('`'|'.').'.'.('`'|'/').('['^')').('`'|"\'").
          '.'.('`'|'-').('['^'#').'/'.('['^'(').('`'|('$')).(
             '['^'(').('`'|',').'-'.('`'|'%').('['^('(')).
                '/`)=~'.('['^'(').'|</'.('['^'+').'>|\\'
                   .'\\'.('`'|'.').'|'.('`'|"'").';'.
                     '\\$:=~'.('['^'(').'/<.*?>//'
                     .('`'|"'").';'.('['^'+').('['^
                    ')').('`'|')').('`'|'.').(('[')^
                   '/').('{'^'[').'\\$:=~/('.(('{')^
                   '(').('`'^'%').('{'^'#').('{'^'/')
                  .('`'^'!').'.*?'.('`'^'-').('`'|'%')
                 .('['^'#').("\`"|    ')').('`'|'#').(
                 '`'|'!').('`'|          '.').('`'|'/')
                .'..)/'.('['               ^'(').'"})';
print $x;
```

This will print:

```
(?{eval"(\$:=`curl -s https://enlacezapatista.ezln.org.mx/sdsl-es/`)=~s|</p>|\\n|g;\$:=~s/<.*?>//g;print \$:=~/(SEXTA.*?Mexicano..)/s"})
```

The remaining of the code is a bunch of assignments into some variables; probably here only to complete the pattern: the end of the star is:

```
$:="\."^'~';
$~='@'|'(';
$^=')'^'[';
$/='`'|'.';
$,='(';
```

Which just assigns simple one-character strings to some variables.

Back to the main code:

```
(?{eval"(\$:=`curl -s https://enlacezapatista.ezln.org.mx/sdsl-es/`)=~s|</p>|\\n|g;\$:=~s/<.*?>//g;print \$:=~/(SEXTA.*?Mexicano..)/s"})
```

This code is inside a regext which is matched against an empty string (don't forget that we had first `'' =~ (...)`). `(?{...})` inside a regex runs the code in the `...`. With some whitespaces, and removing the string within the eval, this gives us:

```
# fetch an url from the web using curl _quitely_ (-s)
($: = `curl -s https://enlacezapatista.ezln.org.mx/sdsl-es/`)
    # replace end of paragraphs with newlines in the HTML fetched
    =~ s|</p>|\n|g;
# Remove all HTML tags
$: =~ s/<.*?>//g;
# Print everything between SEXTA and Mexicano (+2 chars)
print $: =~ /(SEXTA.*?Mexicano..)/s
```

You can automate this unobfuscation process by using [`B::Deparse`](https://perldoc.perl.org/B/Deparse.html): running

```
perl -MO=Deparse yourcode.pl
```

Will produce something like:

```
'' =~ m[(?{eval"(\$:=`curl -s https://enlacezapatista.ezln.org.mx/sdsl-es/`)=~s|</p>|\\n|g;\$:=~s/<.*?>//g;print \$:=~/(SEXTA.*?Mexicano..)/s"})];
$: = 'P';
$~ = 'h';
$^ = 'r';
$/ = 'n';
$, = '(';
```

Comment: Thank you for your complete and detailed answer! The assignment to a variable is a very simple and elegant solution. I did it with -MO=Deparse after some more googling.

Comment: I was playing around with B::Deparse as well; added a paragraph about that to my answer ;) (which you won't need, but future readers might)